# add multiple shipping rules woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two shipping method with separate price. I am adding shipping method/rule using the following add_rate function

```
$this->add_rate( array(
      'id'   => $this->id,
      'label' => 'Australia Post (Express)',
      'cost'   => $APCOSTex

    ));
```

This is showing perfectly. But how to add another rules? WHen i am trying to double this function like following

```
$this->add_rate( array(
      'id'   => $this->id,
      'label' => 'Australia Post (Express)',
      'cost'   => $APCOSTex

    ));
    $this->add_rate( array(
      'id'   => $this->id,
      'label' => 'Australia Post (standard)',
      'cost'   => $APCOSTst

    ));
```

This is showing only one shipping method on checkout page. How to add multiple shipping method using add_rate?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the context where you code runs ? thx

Answer (score 4):

In case you didn't solve this out, it is about changing the ID my friend:

```
$this->add_rate( array(
      'id'   => 'id1',
      'label' => 'Australia Post (Express)',
      'cost'   => $APCOSTex

    ));
    $this->add_rate( array(
      'id'   => 'id2',
      'label' => 'Australia Post (standard)',
      'cost'   => $APCOSTst

    ));
```

Hope this helps :)